# How to send JsonResult data to javascript varible and use the variable in map.addLayer function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to send JSON data to a javascript variable. JSON data was generated in Jsonresult method. I want to parse that data in a JS variable and that use that variable in a map.AddLayer() function in Mapbox.

I have tried to send the data with a model in View script like this

```
var mymapData = @Model.LocationData;
```

This is my JsonResult method to generate JSON data:

```
public JsonResult GetLocationdData()
{

    Location aLocation = new Location();

    LocationData aLocationData = new LocationData();

    aLocationData.type = "Feature";
    aLocationData.properties = new Properties
    {
        title = "Narayanganj Red Crescent Unit",
        description = "Established at 2002",
        division = "Dhaka",
        totalProjects = 3,
        beneficiaries = 10,
        totalVolunteers = 23,
        totalStaffs = 10
    };
    aLocationData.properties.projectList.Add("Project - 1");
    aLocationData.properties.projectList.Add("Project - 2");
    aLocationData.geometry = new Geometry
    {
        type = "Point",
        coordinates = new List<double>()
        {
            90.499416,
            23.626224
        }

    };


    aLocation.features.Add(aLocationData);
    aLocation.type = "FeatureCollection";
    return Json(aLocation, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here I am sending the JSON data in a ViewModel by casting it to object type:

```
var locationData = GetLocationdData();
homeViewModel.LocationData = locationData.Data;
```

---

This is my script file:

```
var mymapData = @Model.LocationData;

map.on('load', function () {

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "places",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": mymapData
        },
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "circle-15",
            "icon-size": 1.25
        }
    });
});
```

---

I want to get these JSON data under source.data from JSONResult method. Below are the static data:

```
map.on('load', function () {

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "places",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                features: [
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "properties": {
                            "title": "Narayanganj Red Crescent Unit",
                            "description": "",
                            "division": "Dhaka",
                            "TotalProject": "3",
                            "TotalStaff": "10",
                            "Volunteers": "14",
                            "Beneficiary": "12",
                            "ProjectList": ["Project-1", "Project-2", "Project-3"]

                        },
                        "geometry": {
                            "coordinates": [
                                90.499416,
                                23.626224
                            ],
                            "type": "Point"
                        }
                    },
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "circle-15",
            "icon-size": 1.25
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try once with `var mymapData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Model` with [Json.Encode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.json.encode?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) method, it converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

*Use*

```
var mymapData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

*instead of*

```
var mymapData = @Model.LocationData;
```